# Java regex not capturing right most numbered group

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import amdocs.mcfw.constants.McConstants.MappingRegExConstants;

public class RegExTest {

    public static final String DECLARATION_REGEX = "(int|long)\\s*(\\S+);";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "int a;";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(DECLARATION_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(matcher);
        printGroups(matcher);

    }

    private static void printGroups(Matcher m) {

        System.out.println(m.find());
        for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i +": " +m.group(i));

        }

    }
}
```

Above code illustrates a RegEx to match a declaration instruction, I expect 3 groups in the output as below.

**0: int a** -> Full match

**1: int** -> Type

**2: a** -> Var name

But I'm getting only the first two groups not the third one. Actually I have tried with many variations of the problem and it seems RegEx engine always discard the right most numbered group until you explicitly wrap that right-most numbered group with another numbered group i.e., in our example rewriting "(\\S+)" as "((\\S+))" solves the issue.

But the question is if as per documentation whatever you define under round brackets will be captured as a number group, why do we have to cover the rightmost group with two set of braces?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/OLj2wN/2

Comment: You need `i <= matcher.groupCount();` to iterate through all the groups

Comment: Opps.. that's really silly of me :(
Thank you very much @anubhava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't loop over all the groups. Fact that regEx engine always put the whole match as the 0th group implies that groupCount will always be one more than the expected groups.

Comment: Capturing Groups `()` start with number 1. onward. So, `for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)`.